# Tabulator - moving rows within the same table into another group section

Tags: javascript, tabulator

This works great when I have a table and move a row into another group section.
However, when I move a row and drop it into a child row(part of tree)  the rowMoved will not fire.
Is there another listener to capture when you drop the row into a child row?

rowMoved:function(row){

}

Comment: I get this error in the tabulator code:
Uncaught TypeError: n.insertRow is not a function
    at s.moveRowActual (batch.js?agile_global_admin_condition=true&baseurl-check-resources=true&healthcheck-resources=true&jag=true&jaguser=true&jira.create.linked.issue=true&locale=en-US&richediton=true&user-logged-in=true:7693)

Comment: you cannot currently drop rows "into" a child of another row, this feature is not yet supported

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Oli!
Is there any type of event that I can capture that will fire?
I was thinking... as a working around, if the user attempts to move a row and it fails, I could wrap it a try catch and just say 'Operation is not allowed' as a work around.

Comment: this depends on how your table is setup, can you post a link to a js fiddle in your question that demonstrates the issue and how your table is setup, it will make it easier to post the answer for your specific table